# Bcrypt compare password stays invalid even is password is correct on login

Tags: mysql, node.js, bcrypt

I'm trying to compare a password from my database with the password on login.

`req.body.wachtwoord` is the password send to the API to check.

`results.0.wachtwoord` is the hashed password in the database.

It doesn't matter if I enter the right or wrong password on login, the error still says `Password is invalid`

Here is my code for login to compare the 2 passwords:

```
bcrypt.compare(req.body.wachtwoord, results[0].wachtwoord, function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
        logger.error(err);
        res.status(err.status).json(err);
    }
    if (res) {
        // Send JWT
        logger.info("passwords matched, sending userinfo en valid token.");
        const { password, ...userinfo } = results[0];
        const payload = { docentID: userinfo.docentID, };

        logger.debug(payload);

        jwt.sign(
             payload,
             jwtSecretKey, { expiresIn: "25d" },
             function(err, token) {
                 if (token) {
                     logger.info("User logged in, sending: ", userinfo);
                     res.status(200).json({
                         status: 200,
                         result: {...userinfo, token },
                     });
                 }
             }
        );
    } else {
        logger.info("Password invalid");
            res.status(401).json({
                status: 401,
                message: "Password invalid.",
                datetime: new Date().toISOString,
            });
    }
});
```

Here's my full repo if you want to take a look for an error.
The password is being hashed in `user.controller.js` and is compared to the database in `auth.controller.js`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you check bcytpt.compare callback's second res argument? res might not be http response instance.

Comment: Good point, `res` is being reused as well. But that wouldn't cause the compare to fail.

Comment: I changed the function to not use `res` but that changes nothing. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My password was being stored in the database at 50 characters. This is too short for the bycrypt hash. I changed the length to 60 and now my compare works.
There was nothing wrong with my code for comparing and hashing ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing against `results[0].wachtwoord`, but further up in the code the property seems to be called `password`:

```
const { password, ...userinfo } = results[0];
        ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: That's not where it is going wrong. And that password is only to get that value out of the body.

Comment: So are you sure that `results[0].wachtwoord` is a proper bcrypt hash? Have you made sure that the code where it's written to the database produces the correct output?

Comment: Also, if `results[0].wachtwoord` contains the hash, not `results[0].password`, you're returning the hash as part of `userinfo` in the JSON response to the client...

Comment: I logged the `results[0].wachtwoord` and it contains the hash that is stored in the database

Comment: @Sheets so it starts with `$2b`, presumably? Have you validated that the code creating the hash works properly?

Comment: My hashed password indeed starts with `$2b`. And the code hashing my passwords works fine.

Comment: @Sheets other than the `res` aliasing, there's nothing wrong with the code you're showing, so the issue is with code that's _not_ being shown.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245286/discussion-between-sheets-and-robertklep).