# Mysql indices query optimization

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a table that has the following columns:

```
id (int)
token (varchar)
title (varchar)
category (varchar)
device
reported_at(date)
created_at (date)
updated_at (date)
```

This table has a composite index on the following columns with this order:

```
category, token, reported_at
```

I am querying the count of bugs that were created at the following date '2019-03-01' or later.

I need help to improve the search time to be faster than this basic query

```
select count(*)
from bugs
where created_at >= '2019-03-01'
```

I am using a Mysql database

Comment: You need an index on the `created_at` column.

Comment: The composite index you have will not be used in your query for created_at column.  Are you unable to ALTER TABLE bugs ADD INDEX created_at?

Comment: This is the third identical question from three different users in the past 2 hours. Are you all doing a homework assignment for the same class or something? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72476422 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72476423

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please understand that this community isn’t a replacement for you doing prior research. You should always first turn to a search engine, and say search for terms like "how to improve search on mysql" which got me to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-optimization.html for example.

Comment: Not to mention there are already SEs dedicated to helping DBAs improve their stuff.